# unwrap() / remove specific HTML element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to remove the strong element from this HTML using jQuery but cant make it work (note: message_id here is actually PHP code, but I removed it for readability):

```
<p class="comments-layout" id="strong_messageid"><strong>text</strong></p>
```

I've tried his:

```
$('#strong'+messageid).children().first().unwrap();
```

after rearranging but did not work.

Comment: Please replace the PHP code with the rendered HTML.

Comment: $(".comments-layout").unwrap();

Comment: okay I removed the php code and rearanged strong and p for good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the `<p>` element, you have to select the children elements and then unwrap it to remove just the `#strongX` element.

```
$('#strong'+messageid).children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

As [**.unwrap**](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method actually removes the parent element of the selected one, you probably need something like this:

```
$('#strong'+messageid).children().first().unwrap();
```

Can't help wondering, though, why it's `<p>` element wrapped in `<strong>`, not vice versa?

Comment: I tried your solution and rearranged the p and strong tag for good practice but did not manage to make it work.

Comment: @user1683645 And it shouldn't work now, as you've both changed the structure AND reassigned an id to the wrapper element now. It'd really help if you describe your problem in more details; the way I see it, you can just run `.replace(/<\/?strong>/, '')` over `innerHTML` of that element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#strong'+messageid)
    .children()
    .insertAfter( $('#strong'+messageid) );
$('#strong'+messageid).remove();
```

if you've text nodes inside your strong use `contents` instead of `children`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the p element but just remove the surrounding strong tag, you could try:

```
//get the DOM elements contained within the strong tag first then replace the strong tag
//with these elements
$element_contents = $('#strong'+  $messageid).contents();
$('#strong'+  $messageid).replaceWith($element_contents);
```